# Can I force all the sub sites to be using the same master page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have created a sub site and I define a custom master page for it. Then I save it as a  template. After that I started creating sub sites based on the template, where all the subsites get the custom master page as defined in the template.

Now let say I have 20 sub sites , and I want to do a change to all the sub sites master pages such as changing the footer or the search box location. Currently each of the 20 sub site have a separate master page and to apply such a change I will need to modify the related 20 master pages separately. Now since I will always need the same master page to be used inside all the subsites including any future changes , so is there a way in SP to force the sub sites to be using the same master page (shared master page) , so if I modify the shared master page it will affect all the sub sites at once ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can open top level site then

`Site Settings` -> `Master Page` -> Check `Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting` and click `Ok`

This will set top level master page to all Sub Sites.

Comment: can you advice from where i can get this feature. now i went to our site collection >> site settings >> Web Designer Galleries  >>Master pages. then i select the seatle.master but i can not find the option to  "reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting" ??

Comment: You should enable publishing feature

Comment: And you should not go to web designer galleries, what Amal mentioned is inside site collection administration, then "Look and Feel" -> Master Page

Comment: @Gwny there is no option named "Master Page " under the "Look and Feel",, should i enable publishing feature inside my site collection , to have this option ?

Comment: Why not try it out? You can deactivate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below script to change the masterpage for all subsites.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal/sites/collaboration
$site | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object { $_.MasterUrl = "/sites/collaboration/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";$_.Update() }
$site.Dispose()
```

[Changing the master page on SharePoint sites with PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/09/changing-master-page-on-sharepoint.html)

Also check this one: [Powershell so all of subsites/sub-sub sites inherit from Parent site's master page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/446dde2d-21b8-4c9e-915e-25eee728064d/powershell-so-all-of-subsitessubsub-sites-inherit-from-parent-sites-master-page?forum=sharepointadminprevious)